# How to use sonst?

Tags: meaning, usage

As far as I've understood, **sonst** refers to anything else but this particular thing your talking about right now. So, for instance, if I'm trying to say in German

> I don't care about anything else but this particular issue

would

> sonst ist mir egal

be correct? Or what would be ok? Can you please explain me the correct way of using this word please.

Comment: "sonst" is not a good way of translating nouns. "Anything else but X"  is better rendered as "Alles (andere) ausser X".

Comment: "Sonst" is an adverb and doesn't refer to any particular thing. It means "else", "otherwise".

Comment: Someone please mention _sonstiges / anderes_, _ansonsten_, _alles sonst / sonst alles_, _samt und sonders_ in their answer.

Comment: I'd apprecite very much if someone expained what Crissov just wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good translations for

> I don't care about **anything else** but this particular issue.

is

> Ich interessiere mich für **sonst nichts** als dieses spezielle Problem.

Some other examples:

- > You told me, you remember Lisa. **Who else** do you remember?
  >   Du hast es mir gesagt, du erinnerst dich an Lisa. An **wen sonst** erinnerst du dich?
- > Today an exception, **otherwise** I do not sleep until 11 o'clock in the morning.
  >   Heute eine Ausnahme, **sonst** schlafe ich nicht bin 11 Uhr morgens.
- > Is there **no other** expert in this field?
  >   Gibt es **sonst keine** Experten auf diesem Gebiet?
- > Would you like **anything else?**
  >   Möchtest du **sonst noch etwas?**